# Android Studio - Emulator Doesn't Launch App

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I have created an app and when I launch the emulator, the emulator loads, but my app never shows. In the run log all it says is

```
Device connected: emulator-5554
```

And nothing else. My logcat is spewing out tons of stuff, some errors, but no errors that appear to be errors caused by my code. I use HAMx for my emulator and my projects target sdk is the same as the emulators sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Check which images you are using mostly HAXM is used for intel based android emulator not an arm emulator